# Could not get unknown property from external gradle file

Tags: android, gradle

In app directory I have **constants.gradle**:

```
def APP_NAME_RELEASE = "My Project name"
```

In **app/build.gradle** I have:

```
apply from: 'constants.gradle'
println("APP_NAME_RELEASE = " + APP_NAME_RELEASE)
```

But when I try to build I get error:

```
Error:(2, 0) Could not get unknown property 'APP_NAME_RELEASE' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
<a href="openFile:myproject\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExtraPropertiesExtension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html) :

**constants.gradle**

```
ext.APP_NAME_RELEASE = "My Project name"
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply from: 'constants.gradle'
println("APP_NAME_RELEASE = " + ext.APP_NAME_RELEASE)
```

Comment: It could be better to specify domain object  ( `ext.APP_NAME_RELEASE` -> `project.ext.APP_NAME_RELEASE`)